# How to display table with grouping

Tags: angularjs

I need to create a table that can group by a object property. I am unable to use ngTable for this so I am hoping there is a way to do it with a filter or nested ng-repeats.

[plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/zLetOSaEKVkdQR5mVYKU?p=preview)

```
"CompanyId": "40",
"CompanyName": "XEREX",
    "CompanyEmployees": {
        "_id": "544",
         "CompanyEmployeeFirstName": "Taylor",
         "CompanyEmployeeLastName": "Bartlett",
         "CompanyEmployeeState": "Vermont"
```

the table needs to show a list of the Employees Names and they need to be grouped by there State.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a couple ways you might handle this besides writing your own filters.  First you could use a library like lodash or underscore (not demonstrated here) to do the group by in your controller or include this nifty filter library so as to not reinvent the wheel and write your own filter.

https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter#groupby

Plunker:  http://plnkr.co/edit/okEpdguH1FW2IKQX24TS?p=preview

Here is the code to do a grouping on the state:

```
<table ng-repeat="state in customers |  groupBy:'CompanyEmployees.CompanyEmployeeState'">
  <tr>
    <td>{{state[0].CompanyEmployees.CompanyEmployeeState}}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr ng-repeat="customer in state">
    <td>{{customer.CompanyEmployees.CompanyEmployeeFirstName}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```